# Path isn't changing using Router instead of BrowserRouter

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

To solve a problem cause by Server Side Rendering, I had to change `BrowserRouter` to `Router` and pass `history` by using a function:

```
function App() {

    const history = createMemoryHistory();

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <Router history={history}>
                <ScrollToTop>
                    <Header/>
                    <Route path="/project/:name" component={Project}/>
                    <Route path="/about" component={About}/>
                    <div className="hs">
                        <Route path={["/", "/project/:name"]} exact component={CartHolder}/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="hs-mobile">
                        <Route path="/" exact component={CartHolderMobile}/>
                    </div>
                </ScrollToTop>
            </Router>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Ever since I've made those changes, the path isn't changing anymore. In other words, it's always `localhost:3000`, no matter what route I'm on. How so?

Comment: @JoseFelix Thanks, did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add Switch.

```
import { Route, Router, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {

    const history = createMemoryHistory();

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <Router history={history}>
                <ScrollToTop>
                    <Header/>
                    <Switch>
                    <Route path="/project/:name" component={Project}/>
                    <Route path="/about" component={About}/>
                    <div className="hs">
                        <Route path={["/", "/project/:name"]} exact component={CartHolder}/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="hs-mobile">
                        <Route path="/" exact component={CartHolderMobile}/>
                    </div>
                    </Switch>
                </ScrollToTop>
            </Router>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but somehow the paths I'm targeting with `Link` are still not showing up, additionally this made `CartHolder` disappear navigation to `Project`, even though it shouldn't and didn't before.

Answer (score 0):

Create the history object outside of the component, since it is creating a new instance each time you re-render; also, try using `createBrowserHistory()` instead of `createMemoryHistory()`:

```
const history = createBrowserHistory();

function App() {   

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <Router history={history}>
                <ScrollToTop>
                    <Header/>
                    <Route path="/project/:name" component={Project}/>
                    <Route path="/about" component={About}/>
                    <div className="hs">
                        <Route path={["/", "/project/:name"]} exact component={CartHolder}/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="hs-mobile">
                        <Route path="/" exact component={CartHolderMobile}/>
                    </div>
                </ScrollToTop>
            </Router>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: This helps, but brings back the error I had with server side rendering: Browser History need a DOM.

Comment: Are you using next.js?

Comment: No, I don't think I do.